# correcting and fix explode and sort to show the result in PHP

Tags: php, string, sorting, foreach, explode

I just create a color extractor for my gallery. for every image i have a row in database for colors, this is a part of one of those row in database.

Example of row:

```
CCCCCC,CCCCFF,99CCCC,333333,9999CC,999999,CCFFFF,000000,000033,669999,666699,333366,003333,336666,666666,FFFFFF,FF9900,333300...
```

*i didn't add all colors in here because is too long.*

Now, in photo page i need to show those colors, but not all of them. for example just 20 color. so i wrote this code:

```
$all_colors = $db->super_query("SELECT color 
FROM colors 
WHERE photo_id='{$photoid}'
");

$list = explode(',',$all_colors['color'], 20);//Select 20 colors
sort($list); //And sorting colors

foreach ($list as $item){
echo $item."<br>";
}
```

Now the problem is, this is the result from that code:

```
000000
000033
003333
330000
333300
333333
333366
336666
663300
666633
666666
666699
669999
996633,FFFFCC,CC9966,CCCC99,663333,FF9933,FFCC66,CC9933,CC6600,666600,996600,003300,999966,FFCC33,CCFFCC,996666,999933,FFCC00,CC9999,FFFF99,FF9999
999999
9999CC
99CCCC
CCCCCC
CCCCFF
CCFFFF
```

You can see a line with too many colors!

Result must be like this:

```
000000
000033
003333
330000
333300
333333
333366
336666
663300
666633
666666
666699
669999
996633
999999
9999CC
99CCCC
CCCCCC
CCCCFF
CCFFFF
```

How i can fix this code?

Comment: explode 21 colours, then pop the last one before sorting

Comment: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

Comment: @Mark Baker i need more help. what is pop the last one? :(

Comment: http://phptutorial.info/?explode - shows - "If limit is set and positive, the returned array will contain a maximum of limit elements with the last element containing the rest of string."...so I believe you'll need to leave off the ",20" and then just process the first 20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option #1**

```
$all_colors = $db->super_query("SELECT color 
FROM colors 
WHERE photo_id='{$photoid}'
ORDER BY color
LIMIT 20");

$list = explode(',',$all_colors['color']);

foreach ($list as $item){
    echo $item."<br>";
}
```

**Option #2**

```
$all_colors = $db->super_query("SELECT color 
FROM colors 
WHERE photo_id='{$photoid}'");

$list = array_slice(explode(',',$all_colors['color']), 0, 20);//Select 20 colors
sort($list); //And sorting colors

foreach ($list as $item){
    echo $item."<br>";
}
```

**Option #3**

```
$all_colors = $db->super_query("SELECT color 
FROM colors 
WHERE photo_id='{$photoid}'");

$list = explode(',',$all_colors['color'], 21);//Select 20 colors
if (count($list) == 21)
    array_pop($list);
sort($list); //And sorting colors

foreach ($list as $item){
    echo $item."<br>";
}
```

Comment: thank you mark, i know how to use database and sql, but i cant use LIMIT 20 in one row. all colors are in just one row. your third method is best choice for me. thanks

Comment: Designing the database using 3rd normal form would help

Answer (score 1):

Use [`array_slice()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to extract the first 20 elements of the array.

```
$list = array_slice(explode(',',$all_colors['color'], 21), 0, 20);
print_r($list);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => CCCCCC
    [1] => CCCCFF
    [2] => 99CCCC
    [3] => 333333
    [4] => 9999CC
    [5] => 999999
    [6] => CCFFFF
    [7] => 000000
    [8] => 000033
    [9] => 669999
    [10] => 666699
    [11] => 333366
    [12] => 003333
    [13] => 336666
    [14] => 666666
    [15] => FFFFFF
    [16] => FF9900
    [17] => 333333
    [18] => 333366
    [19] => 336666
)
```

Comment: I fixed the missing parenthesis, was that the problem?

Comment: thank you but your code is not working! there is not any result in echo!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$all_colors = $db->super_query("SELECT color 
FROM colors 
WHERE photo_id='{$photoid}'
");

//Select all colors, third parameter limits, but last one will be remaining string
$list = explode(',',$all_colors['color']);
sort($list); //And sorting colors

$c = 0;
foreach ($list as $item){
echo $item."<br>";
//if c equals 20 break
if($c==20)
break;
$c++;
}
```

Noe: This is quick suggestion, method that works. I am sure there are better ways doing same thing.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i cant use this method, because i need to select 20 color first and then sorting them, so i cant use break in foreach. anyway problem is fixed :D